# Bootstrap fluid layout, wrong margin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Edit: I realize this might be a Safari issue? I don't see the same in Firefox**

The following image is taken from the Bootstrap documentation, [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem). What I'm wondering is why there is a 2px margin to the right of the rightmost "Fluid 6" element. Shouldn't that element align all the way to the right? And what can I do to fix it?

[image]

Enhanced image:[image]

Comment: The margin's there in Chrome, too, so probably a WebKit thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just `span6`, it's anything that isn't 100% of the width.

[image]

Notice how all but the last row have this problem. The problem is that Bootstrap specifies widths as percents.

For example, for `span6`,

```
.span6 {
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
}
```

There is also a space between the two span elements,

```
margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
```

Adding these up does not result in a nice even number, so we sometimes end up a pixel under. Other than setting fixed values for the widths and margins, not much can be done.

`span12` has a 100% width:

```
.span12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

which is exactly that, so there's no problem with rounding.